# NHtmlUnit error "Could not generate DH keypair"

Tags: c#, .net, nhtmlunit

Everytime I try to scrape a page e.g.

```
 HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage)client.GetHtmlPage("https://groceries.morrisons.com/");
```

I get the following error:

> Additional information: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate
>   DH keypair

Web Client settings

```
    NHtmlUnit.WebClient client = new NHtmlUnit.WebClient();
    client.Options.CssEnabled = false;
    client.Options.JavaScriptEnabled = false;
    client.Options.AppletEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:

[Is there a way to force NHTMLUNIT to Ignore Page JavaScript errors and Continue Script Execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15969821/805284)

Try ignoring the errors. 
If that does not work, you are most likely out of luck due to a java bug leading to this error due to a too long keylength of the TLS encryption.

Comment: Im not sure how i can fixed this since im using a NHtmlUnit liprary :/ As far as i know NHtmlUnit usis IKVM to run java code